# How to pass express route handling to the next middleware and breaking current block of code?

Tags: javascript, express

My route handler on express app looks like following:

```
app.use('/', function(res, req, next) => {
  if (!authorised) next();
  f1();
  f2();
});
```

How can I avoid running f1() and f2() without having to introduce conditionals like:

```
app.use('/', function(res, req, next) => {
  if (authorised) {
    f1(); 
    f2();
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Introducing `return next()` breaks proper route handling flow.

Comment: What about `next(); return;` ?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is

```
app.use('/', function(res, req, next) => {
  //early return
  if (!authorised) { next(); return; }
   // Still valid

  //if (!authorised) return next();
   /* Still valid 
  if (!authorised) {
         //do something like log unauthorized access 
         return next();
   }*/

  f1();
  f2();
});
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Couldn't you also just do `return next();`?

Comment: @Ashley B what I wanted to convey was *if you don't wanna use else* you'll need to return, he already suggested 'return next' so I didn't mention it... But still I'd update my answer... Thanks.